# How to add a particular migration with multiple entries in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, model, rails-migrations

I want to create a new field in my rails database which has multiple fields associated with it and can take multiple sets of entries. For example in Linkedin,

a user adds a job with information like title, description and duration and can create multiple jobs associated to his profile.

How do I build a similar system in rails, is it possible using only migrations or do I have to create a new model for it and associate it with a particular user.

Which will be the correct way to go through this issue?

Comment: you need to create a `Job` model for example, and associate it with `User`, so that a User has_many jobs, and a Job belongs_to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Job model, setup the relationship between the User and the Job models using a foreign key(user_id) and then inside User.rb put *has_many :jobs* and inside Job.rb put *belongs_to :user*, that way you will be able to create as many jobs as you want for a user. Not sure if this answers your question but I think that would be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks :) I was thinking the same but thought if there is a simpler or conventional way to do it.